# ZedGraph v. 5.15, multi y-axis alignment

Tags: alignment, zedgraph

The issue I have is when using two Y-axes (y1 and y2), wherein the y1 value is: (min,max) = (zero,positive) and the y2 value (min, max) = (negative, positive), in such case, the zero marking of y1 coincides with the max (negative) value of the y2 axis (through the x-axis), that is the problem since I want zero point of both y-axis to flush together.

If I knew the value of min and max for both y-axes then this problem could be fixed easily, but I only know whether the range starts from positive or negative value, not the value itself.

Note that this problem is not there when both y-axes have values (data points) above zero. They automatically align such that both their zero points passes through the x-axis.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do so by fixing the proportion between axis:

```
public void SetY1Y2CommonZero()
{
   AxisChange();

   ZedGraph.Scale source, dest;

   if (GraphPane.YAxis.Scale.Min != 0)
   {
       source = GraphPane.YAxis.Scale;
       dest = GraphPane.Y2Axis.Scale;
   }
   else if (GraphPane.Y2Axis.Scale.Min != 0)
   {
       source = GraphPane.Y2Axis.Scale;
       dest = GraphPane.YAxis.Scale;
   }
   else
   {
       return;
       // do nothing - both axis have 0 on min...
   }


   double proportion =  source.Max / source.Min;

   // we want to ENLARGE the other axis accordingly:
   if (proportion * dest.Min > dest.Max)
       dest.Max = proportion * dest.Min;
   else
       dest.Min = dest.Max / proportion;
}
```